# Deploy node app and mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-deployment-project

How to deploy node application into services supported mysql. I've try with c9, nodejitsu, but they aren't support database mysql. Please help me!

Comment: You know, you don't have to host your SQL and node.js on the exact same server

Answer (score 1):

A free and good solution would be AppFog. They have MySQL Database as well as MongoDB. They will soon support websockets as well.

For more have a look at this page - https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Node-Hosting